# Editing Embed DiscordAPIError: Cannot edit a message authored by another user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

### Research/Things I've Tried:

I know that there's been pre-existing questions written about this, and I've tried implementing [what this answer suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66164883/15073477) but to no avail. It's not even used in the code posted in this question.

As suggested from the second "resource", even if I were to edit the embed object itself, it gives me the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined` as stated from [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036269/discord-js-edit-embed-with-command). After a little bit of looking through the documentation, I realized that the `MessageEmbed` object itself has no `edit` method, which makes me extremely confused (Source: [Discord.js Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=spliceFields)).

---

### Code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    //could be triggered via a different method, but it's only meant to test the !edit command
    const StandardEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Test')
        .setDescription('Description')
    message.channel.send(StandardEmbed);

    if (message.content === '!edit') {

        //oldEmbed is rather extraneous, I don't even call it at all...
        //let oldEmbed = message.channel.messages.fetch('833863581073932329'); 

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("New Embed!")
            .setDescription("Description")
            .addField('name', 'value');

        message.edit(embed);
    }
});
```

---

### Note:

- Using a `Client#message` listener
- Using a MessageEmbed constructor instead of an embed object

May be important, may not.

---

### TL;DR

I'm trying to edit an embed once a user sends a message, ex. "!edit" but I receive an error (mentioned in the title) instead.

---

### Similar Questions/Resources:

1. [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66164883/15073477)
2. [Another similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036269/discord-js-edit-embed-with-command)
3. [Discord.js Documentation - MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=spliceFields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like:

```
   message.channel.messages.fetch('833863581073932329').then(msg =>{
     const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("New Embed!")
            .setDescription("Description")
            .addField('name', 'value');
msg.edit(embed)
})
```

You are trying to edit `let oldEmbed` but you did `message.edit` which means you are trying to edit `!edit`